# Synonymity of "simple" and "basic"

Tags: synonyms

If I have two ways of doing the same thing, one requiring more input or effort than the other but also allowing for more customization, how should I label the two?

> The ***simple*** way and the *custom* way
>
> The ***basic*** way and the *custom* way

Are *simple* and *basic* really synonyms in this situation?

Comment: Well, nobody programs in Visual Simple, though lots of simple people program in Visual Basic, so these are not synonyms :D If anyone is looking for me, I'm gone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Simple* and *basic* are not completely synonymous, although they are generally similar. According to the OALD, *basic* [means](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/basic_1):

> forming the part of something that is most necessary and from which other things develop

So something is *basic* if it can serve as a building block for other things. For example, an atom could be considered a basic part of chemistry because other compounds build up from it.

*Simple* [means](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/simple):

> not complicated; easy to understand or do

Some people may say that an iPod is simple to use--it is very intuitive. An iPod, however, is complex and wouldn't be described as basic.

So in your case, I would think that it depends on what these "ways" are. If the non-complex way is the building block for the complex way, use *basic*. If both methods accomplish the same ends, and don't overlap as much, use *simple*.

**Note** that you *can* consider the two words synonyms if you use secondary definitions. You could use either word, if you wanted, and still be correct.

Answer (score 7):

Simple is *uncomplicated*, while basic is *rudimentary*.Which do you think describes your task better?

Comment: I think this answer is comprehensive enough.

Comment: @Braveyard: Not only that, but adding too much verbiage runs the risk of introducing irrelevant, confusing, or even incorrect information into an answer, diluting its value. I find this answer not only shorter than the accepted one, but clearer, more informative, and more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes basic is used to mean foundational. I recall from one of my college texts: [http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Algebra-Second-Nathan-Jacobson/dp/0486471896/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1314548545&sr=8-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486471896)

The basic algebra they talk about is groups, rings, fields and a algebras.